# Javascript @AndroidFindBy @iOSFindBy annotations?

Tags: javascript, selenium, appium

In Java for Appium we have the beautiful @AndroidFindBy @iOSFindBy annotations to let you reuse test cases without writing a bunch of logic to handle is it an IOS app, or Android app.

Has anyone been able to implement a library in JS, or is there any mobile testing framework in JS that has these sort of locator functions built in?

Thanks